# How to migrate websocket server to wss (websocket secure)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, wss

I have to build a client-server application that uses websocket secure for communication between the parties. In order to build it, I used this repo as a skeleton:

https://github.com/radu-matei/websocket-manager

This also comes to the following blog post:

https://radu-matei.com/blog/aspnet-core-websockets-middleware/

I managed to create the ws communication. However, I have to create a wss communication and I can't seem to figure out how to do this. After changing ws:// to wss:// and http to https, if I access localhost the connection will be secure. But if I try to access 127.0.0.1, the communication won't be secure.

I understand that I should use self-signed certificates, but I don't know how to integrate them in the code present in the first link. Can you help?

Comment: After applying SSL to your application it is now running in HTTPS protocol so you have to use `wss://`. That's all there is to it. I am not aware of any other complexities involved. AFAIK if you use `ws://` then it can only connect to an HTTP service.

Comment: If you want to add an SSL to localhost for development purposes then follow [Developing locally with ASP.NET Core under HTTPS, SSL, and Self-Signed Certs](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/developing-locally-with-aspnet-core-under-https-ssl-and-selfsigned-certs)